# JSON Message in MQTTLens

Tags: json, mqtt

When I use MQTTLens to subscribe to a device, it comes out this json message "U\u0002\u0001\u0001px", which translate to this message (Upx). Does anyone know what does the message means? Why this message occurs?

Edit: Turns out it is because my iot router trying to send message in the form of non-ascii characters.

Comment: I'd guess the message is something like 75 02 01 01 70 78 (hex bytes); MQTT lens is attempting to display this as a Unicode string (but some characters are unprintable). An MQTT message is just a series of bytes; we would need more information in order to help (e.g. what is sending the message).

Comment: Re your update - an MQTT message can be any series of bytes. There is no requirement for it to be ASCII.  As ASCII is not the most efficient method of encoding a message many devices don't use it.